# Zend Controller preDispatch preprocessing interfering with dispatch

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've refactored some common behaviour that was repeated at the top of my Controller Actions into a preDispatch method - this is great, except that I'm having to live to general 400 errors even where there really should be a 404.

This is because the default preDispatch method doesn't know what Action is required - so I can't test to see if it exists and 404 if it doesn't.

Other than completely the Zend Controller's dispatch() method and passing the Action name to preDispatch - is there are better solution?

Update: please note, this is Zend Framework 1.10

Comment: you have the request object available so you can check yourself

Comment: quoting my own comment below: 'the action name is not the same as the action ''method'' name'

Comment: what is an action "method" name? you are doing some redirects or calling some other object in you action?

Comment: the getActionName method for the request object returns the hyphenated action name (since this is how we define our URLs) - this is formatted by the dispatcher to get the method name (camelcase) - as far as I can tell, these dispatcher format methods aren't available to the controller or request object (at least, not without breaking encapsulation)

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    if( $front->getDispatcher()->isDispatchable($request) )  {
        // if dispatchable do some stuff
    } else {
        // else show the error
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I need to play around with some other part of the controller to get this properly working - but it definitely seems to be the right step.

Answer (score 0):

> . . . the default preDispatch method doesn't know what Action is
>   required . . .

You can get the controller and action names in the `preDispatch()` method by calling the following methods on the request object:

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $controller = $request->getControllerName();
    $action = $request->getActionName();
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: ah - but the action name is not the same as the action ''method'' name - I tried this route, and ended up copying swathes of code from the Dispatcher class to get the method name before realising that I was simply heading towards copy-pasta mayhem